# Apply filter on subquery with multiple values

Tags: sql, subquery, in-subquery

I Have a table **USER_DETAILS**
and I have another table named **PASSWORD**

```
USER_DETAILS contains:-
id| name| phone_number

PASSWORD contains:-
id|user_id| password| created_at | password_hint
```

password can contain multiple entries for a user

Now I want to fetch the latest password created_at for a user for which am doing this.

```
select user.id,created_at from user_details as user
where user.id in (select user_id,max(created_at) from password group by user_id)
```

but this will not work because the subquery  is returning multiple values how can I do this with subquery(I know I can do this with join as well but I am looking for a subquery solution )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways, with a subquery you would use a *correlated* query

```
select id, (select max(created_at) from password p where p.user_id=u.id) as created_at
from user_details u
```